# How can I setup vim to automatically convert the line endings of any text file I open to unix if it already isn't unix?

Tags: vim

I'm looking for some sort of plugin/vi-code that detects if there are any `^M` ( carriage returns? ) in any files or any sort of indication that the line endings are not unix, and if so either remove them or run `dos2unix` on the file.

I need this to work automatically before/during the file opening.

Also, for the people who are going to suggest ways of converting the line endings manually, one answer points out do `:set ff=unix` but this doesn't kill `^M` in a unix file, I think.

And isn't there a trick to using `:%s/^M//g` because using a literal `^` wont match the char?

Comment: To type a ^M in vi, whether in text or search & replace, type 'Ctrl-V', 'Ctrl-M'.

Comment: The trick to using `:%s/^M//g` is to enter the `^M` as `<CTRL-v><CR>`.

Comment: If you don't want to have raw control characters in pattern, use `\r`. I personally prefer `<C-v><CR>` when typing in command mode and `\r` when writing a script.

Answer (score 3):

The function below is interesting because 
it keeps the cursor to its original position
put it in your. vimrc

```
" dos2unix ^M
fun! Dos2unixFunction()
    let _s=@/
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    try
        set ff=unix
        w!
        "%s/\%x0d$//e
    catch /E32:/
        echo "Sorry, the file is not saved."
    endtry
    let @/=_s
    call cursor(l, c)
endfun
com! Dos2Unix keepjumps call Dos2unixFunction()
au BufReadPost * keepjumps call Dos2unixFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you flagged this git - you can have git convert line ending s on checkin/out automatically (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)

ps. The trick to doing ^M in a replace is

`:%s/{Ctrl+V}{Ctrl+M}//{Enter}`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to flag it as git... some person was asking me git questions so I had git on my mind. This is a good suggestion though and I'm open to doing this on my VCS, but I'd still like a vim answer.

Comment: Doesn't putting :set ff=unix in the startup file work? Or are these files where something else has already put a literal ^M in the file?

Comment: The latter, I've encountered files where the user puts literal ^M in the file even though the file format is unix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace any ^M in any file you open, an autocmd like the following in you vimrc could help:

```
au BufReadPost * %s/^M//g
```

Inserting the ^M as has been indicated in the previous answer.